# How we can do routing in WSO2 ESB integrator based on the specific property in json

Tags: java, json, wso2

Is there any way in WSO2 ESB integrator, to read a parameter value from the requested json (payload) and based on that value, route the request to different backend endpoints?

Comment: you mean conditional router mediator?

Answer (score 0):

This sample described how to route messages based on content to different backends.https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationPatterns/Content-Based+Router.

In this example xpath expression is given in the [switch mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Switch+Mediator) to extract the value and route, You can use the json path for your requirement.

Example : `<switch source="json-eval($.coordinates.location[0].name)">`

Comment: Thank you so much for your your help @Sashika Wijesinghe